# Google Analytics Experiments without redirect: maldistribution of sessions

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Sorry for my English.

I have created new experiment in Google Analytics, and have used [method without redirects](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/experiments-client-side). And i created tag in Google Tag Manager with this content

```
#script with api
<script src="//www.google-analytics.com/cx/api.js?experiment=1EN3yB34T0WE-0WxSqvsKw"></script>
<script>
    # item ids to launch test
    var itemIds= ['898324', '914734', '904249', '936082', '904275', '951077', '977818', '942227', '933907'];
    if( $.inArray({{productId}}, itemIds) !== -1 ) {
        # get chosed variation
        var chosenVariation = cxApi.chooseVariation();
        $(function(){   
            if (chosenVariation == 1) {
                $('div.orange.service').hide();
                $('div.orange.cardif').hide();
            }
        });

        # make non-interaction hit to send data. Maybe here i get mistake 
        #(hit making by send data to Google Tag Manager, and all events with event === OWOX - will send to Google Analytics)
        dataLayer.push({"event":"OWOX","eventCategory":"Non-Interactions","eventAction":"show","eventLabel":"products","products":[]});
    }
</script>
```

And after 7 days of experiment we have:
[big gap between original variant and variant with alternative design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSMKh.png)

And i want to ask why the gap between original page and page with alternatibe design so big?